# memory ram usage increases after run that vba (copy\paste) sub code

Tags: excel, vba

i need help here . my PC memory ram usage starts to increases gradually after that sub is run,  until it is used completely and the system crashes ,

the code only to copy range from sheet and paste to other sheet

i use windows 10 , and the ram is 16 and i try with 32 ram also the same issue happen to me

the code is here

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("main")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sor4main")
Set rng1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(ws1.Range("E2"), ws1.Range("B:B"), ws1.Range("B:B").Offset(0, 1), "", 0, 1)
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A3:CB3")
    
    ws1.Activate
    rng1.Activate
    ActiveCell.Select

    rng2.Copy
    rng1.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing
Set rng1 = Nothing
Set rng2 = Nothing

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
    
End Sub
```

Comment: By chance I found a solution to the problem

at the end of the code . i add

application.visible = true
application.visible = false

that's it .. I think the program needed to be vented some how to release the ram memory ..

Comment: Welcome ahmad! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your next badge. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: The ranges you are using are huge. column B:B is 1048576 long

Comment: I recommend reading [How to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913882/16578424) and [How to avoid copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64611707/16578424) - if you apply those adivses, the performance will heavily increase

Comment: I'm working on a potato and I couldn't replicate the issue even after trying to make it preform the calculation 30 times in a row.